# Solving a date cycle formula

Tags: excel, date

I am working on the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1="Semi",A2="Japan",MONTH($A$3)<4),DATE(YEAR($A$3),3,31),IF(AND(A1="Semi",A2="Japan",MONTH($A$3)>3),DATE(YEAR($A$3),9,30)))
```

and basically I am trying to find the best formula for a problem I have. In cell `A3` of my spreadsheet I have today's date `=TODAY()`. So let's assume today's date is January 1, 2015. What I want the formula to do is the following:

1. If today's date is before March 31, 2015 then I want the formula to give me March 31, 2015.
2. If today´s date is past March 31, 2015, then I want the formula to give me September 30, 2015.
3. However, if today's date is past September 30, 2015 then I want the formula to give me March 31 for the following year (i.e. March 31, 2016).

I have worked out a formula which satisfies points 1 and 2, but my formula fails to satisfy point 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the requirements include the need to have cells `A1` set to "Semi" and `A2` set to "Japan". For the sake of brevity, those can be pulled out to the outer `if` statement if they will apply to all three of your stated cases.

It looks like you almost have it correct, but try looking at claim 2 in a slightly different way:

2. If today's date is after March 31, 2015 and before September 30, 2015 then I want the formula to give me September 30, 2015.

You handle the "after March 31, 2015" requirement in your if statement already (if it was *before* March 31, then you would never enter the `FALSE` part of the if statement!). Now all you need to do is handle the "before September 30, 2015" requirement, which you can do by selecting all dates with a month less than 10.

The third and final requirement will come in the `FALSE` part of the next if statement. If it is not *before* September 30, 2015, it must be *after* September 30, 2015. You can simply add 1 to the year and create a new date for March 31, 2016.

```
=IF(AND(A1="Semi",A2="Japan"),IF(MONTH(A3)<4,DATE(YEAR(A3),3,31),IF(MONTH(A3)<10,DATE(YEAR(A3),9,30),DATE(YEAR(A3)+1,3,31))),"<Error>")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) can conditionally push your fiscal date ahead 6 months.

```
=IF(AND(A1="Semi", A2="Japan"), IF(MONTH($A$3)<4, DATE(YEAR($A$3), 3, 31), EDATE(DATE(YEAR($A$3), 9, 30), (MONTH($A$3)>9)*6)), "not Semi and Japan")
```

There may be a need to add some year comparisons. The formula currently looks like it will have trouble starting on January of next year in A3.